# Using subset of layerList with arcpy.mp.CreateSharingDraft and ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, map-service

According to the [documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/sharing/createsharingdraft.htm) for `arcpy.mp.CreateSharingDraft()`, the argument `draft_value`
can be

> A Map, Layer or list of layers. You can use a subset of layers from a map to publish.

Passing a map object or a single layer object works as expected. However, I get an error if I try to pass a list of layers (or a subset of layers).

```py
service = "MapServiceDraftExample"
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("MyProject.aprx"))
m = aprx.listMaps("MyMap")[0]
layers = m.layerList()
# works
service_draft = arcpy.sharing.CreateSharingDraft(
  "STANDALONE_SERVER",
  "MAP_SERVICE",
  service,
  m
)
# also works
service_draft = arcpy.sharing.CreateSharingDraft(
  "STANDALONE_SERVER",
  "MAP_SERVICE",
  service,
  layers[0]
)
# does not work
service_draft = arcpy.sharing.CreateSharingDraft(
  "STANDALONE_SERVER",
  "MAP_SERVICE",
  service,
  layers
)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\sharing.py", line 100, in CreateSharingDraft
    map_service.draftValue = draft_value._arc_object #todo: temp fix
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_arc_object'
```

**Am I misunderstanding the documentation or is there some other type of "layer list" object that is expected here?**

Answer (score 1):

I reported this to Esri and after some discussion with the support tech they submitted this enhancement to the Esri development team:

> ENH-000141167
> Synopsis: Remove the list of layers option from the draft_value of the CreateSharingDraft arcpy function documentation as it does not return a result. In the enhancement as well I asked to provide more explanation on what a valid input would be for the list of layers or for it to be removed for clarity.